# Text wrap with box in Basemap

Tags: python-2.7, text, matplotlib-basemap

I'd like to write some text on a world map pointing to several locations. The text to be written for each location is short, a few lines, with one or two words/numbers (i.e earthquake magnitude, location, date). Is there a pythonic way to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `matplotlib-basemap` is based on `matplotlib`, you can simply use

```
plt.text(x,y,'yourtext')
```

to write text onto your map. If you want to have it boxed, add something like:

```
plt.text(x,y,'yourtext',bbox={'pad':10})
```

See also http://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html.